# Change iOS Share Extension name

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, share-extension

Let's say I have an app called `Format App` that has a share extension to let the user share files.

When the iOS menu of all share extensions appears, I want my app to have a different name: `FA`. How can I change the name of my app in the share extension without change it the whole app's name?

I tried:

```
        <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
        <string>FA</string>
```

in the `Info.plist` from the share extension, but it did not work. i also tried to change it from the `Build Settings` from XCODE. The only way I could change it is if I change it from `Info.plist` of the app. I want something similar as `NSExtensionServiceToolbarPaletteLabel`, but that is only for action extension in macOS.

I could do it on Android, is it some weird iOS stuff?